# segmentation failed (core dumped) working with opencv

Tags: opencv, segmentation-fault, runtime-error, coredump

I'm running into a problem, trying to perform a template matching using OpenCV on Ubuntu 18.04LTS

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    int match_method =5;
    string image_window = "Source Image";
    string result_window = "Result window";
    Mat img, templ, result;

    /// Load image and template
    img = imread("./RI2.jpg", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE );
    templ = imread("./Pump2.jpg", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE );

    /// Create windows
    //namedWindow( image_window, WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    //namedWindow( result_window, WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

    /// Source image to display
    Mat img_display;
    img.copyTo( img_display );

    /// Create the result matrix
    int result_cols =  img.cols - templ.cols + 1;
    int result_rows = img.rows - templ.rows + 1;
    result.create( result_rows, result_cols, CV_32FC1 );


    /// Do the Matching and Normalize
    matchTemplate( img, templ, result, match_method );
    normalize( result, result, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );
    Mat resultgrey(result_rows, result_cols, CV_8UC1);

    cout << "resultgrey.size().width: " << resultgrey.size().width << endl;
    cout << "resultgrey.size().height: " << resultgrey.size().height << endl;
    cout << "result.size().width: " << result.size().width << endl;
    cout << "result.size().height: " << result.size().height << endl;

    if( match_method  == 0 || match_method == 1 )
    {
        for (int i=0; i<result.size().width; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<result.size().height; j++)
            {
                if (result.at<float>(i,j)>=0.1)
                {
                    resultgrey.at<int>(i,j)=0;
                }
                else
                {
                    resultgrey.at<int>(i,j)=1;

                }
            }
        }
    }


    else
    {
        for (int i=0; i<result.size().width; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<result.size().height; j++)
            {
                if (result.at<float>(i,j)<=0.98)
                {
                    resultgrey.at<int>(i,j)=0;
                    //cout << "0" << endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    resultgrey.at<int>(i,j)=1;
                    //cout << "1" << endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "3" << endl;

    /// Localizing the objects
    vector<Point> matchLoclist;

    //cout << resultgrey << endl;
    findNonZero(resultgrey, matchLoclist);
    cout << "4" << endl;

    if (matchLoclist.size() == 0)
    {
        cout << "no matches found" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    ///Draw Rectangles on Pumps found in the scene
    for (int i=0; i<matchLoclist.size(); i++)
    {
        //cout << "matchLoclist[i].x: "<<matchLoclist[i].x  << endl << "matchLoclist[i].y: " << matchLoclist[i].y << endl;
        rectangle( img_display, matchLoclist[i], Point( matchLoclist[i].x + templ.cols, matchLoclist[i].y + templ.rows ), Scalar::all(0), 2, 8, 0 );
        rectangle( result, matchLoclist[i], Point( matchLoclist[i].x + templ.cols, matchLoclist[i].y + templ.rows ), Scalar::all(0), 2, 8, 0 );
    }

    imshow( image_window, img_display );
    imshow( result_window, result );

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

as an output i get:

xxx@ubuntu:~/Projects/Template_matching$ ./template_matching

resultgrey.size().width: 1216

resultgrey.size().height: 723

result.size().width: 1216

result.size().height: 723

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

This happens during the double for-loop where either a 1 or a 0 gets written into "resultrgrey" as I never get the "3" as an output from the cout below

if I take different input pictures (espacially smaller ones) the programm tends to run without this error.

I appreciate any help or suggestions!

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write outside of the allocated buffer because of (1) incorrectly specified data types and (2) swapped arguments to `.at`, as @rafix07 has noted.

You create 8-bit matrix (8 in `CV_8UC1`):

```
Mat resultgrey(result_rows, result_cols, CV_8UC1);
```

but try to assign 32-bit values to its elements in double-for loop:

```
resultgrey.at<int>(i,j)=0;
```

Template method `cv::Mat::at` calculates address of the `(i,j)`-th element in memory, based on:

- data type, specified in template instantiation,
- pointer to data start, stored in the `cv::Mat` instance,
- and data stride (distance in bytes between leftmost pixels of two consecutive lines), also stored in the `cv::Mat` instance.

Then it returns reference to it. No checks is performed, for speed, therefore it's your responsibility to submit correct arguments.

Size of `int` is 32 bits on most modern platforms, but can be differrent.

Generally, it is safer to use types from [`stdint.h`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdint/) header, that have explicit length and sign in their names: `uint8_t`, `int32_t`, etc

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Works like a charm now!

Answer (score 1):

Look at reference about `Mat::at` method

> ```
> const _Tp& cv::Mat::at    ( int i0, int i1 ) const 
>   Parameters  
>    i0 Index along the dimension 0
>    i1 Index along the dimension 1
> ```

the first dimenstion is number of rows, the second dim is number of columns, so you should change all lines in your code with `at`

```
resultgrey.at<int>(i,j) // i means col, j means row
```

to

```
resultgrey.at<int>(j,i)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Its these careless mistakes, that sometimes just get me -.-'